# Uploading data via HTTP PUT without multi-part gutter

Tags: ruby, http, put, rest-client, net-http

I'm trying to upload static HTML+friends content to a raw Nexus 3 repository. As far as [the documentation goes](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/raw-repositories#RawRepositories-UploadingFilestoHostedRawRepositories), the only way to upload files is using HTTP PUT. Sure enough,

```
curl -v --user 'user:pw' --upload-file my_file.html  \
    http://my.nexus/repository/my-raw-repo/my_file.html
```

works as expected and the file can be accessed at `http://my.nexus/repository/my-raw-repo/index.html`

Adding this deployment to my Rake process has turned out to be hasslesome, though. Here are some things I have tried.

1. With `net/http`:

   ```
   require 'net/http'
   uri = URI("http://my.nexus/repository/my-raw-repo")
   file = "index.html"
   Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
       request = Net::HTTP::Put.new "#{repo_url}/#{file}"
       request.basic_auth(user, pw)

       <snip>

       response = http.request request
       raise "Upload failed: #{response.code} #{response.message}\n#{response.body}" \
          unless response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
   end
   ```

   I tried several variants for `<snip>`.

   1. Set body to file content as string:

      ```
      request.body = File.read("#{file}")`
      ```

      Request completes without error but Nexus shows file size 0 bytes.
   2. Send form data to file content as stream:

      ```
      request.set_form([['upload', File.open("#{file}")]], 'multipart/form-data')
      ```

      That one is kind of obvious: multi-part gutter is added which Nexus does not remove:

      [image]
2. With `rest-client`:

   ```
   require 'rest-client'
   file = "index.html"
   begin
       RestClient::Request.execute(
           method: :put,
           url: "http://my.nexus/repository/my-raw-repo/#{file}",
           <snip>
           user: user,
           password: pw
       )
   rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => e
       raise "Upload failed: #{e.response}"
   end
   ```

   And for `<snip>` (guessing around the less than clear documentation):

   1. `body: File.read("#{file}")`
       --> 0 bytes.
   2. `payload: File.read("#{file}")`
       --> 0 bytes.
   3. `payload: { file: File.new("#{file}") }`
      --> Multi-part gutter remains.
   4. `payload: { multipart: false, file: File.new("#{file}") }`
      --> Multi-part gutter remains.

   I think I tried several combination more which I don't remember, with similar results.

*Note bene:* I've left out the parts related to SSL with a self-signed certificate because that should be unrelated.

How can I tell either library (or any other) to do PUT with data but without multi-part? Or if that's not the issue, what am I doing wrong?

I want to use an all-Ruby solution (i.e. not delegate to system `curl`) so that the build can be (as) portable (as possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `net/http`, set the request body to the file content as stream:

```
request.body_stream = File.open("#{file}")
request.content_length = File.size("#{file}")
request.content_type = "text/plain" # ?!
```

Determining the proper MIME type from the file alone is an adventure in itself.

Comment: I missed this due do idiocy (I had `File.read` and noticed only when writing up the question); I'd still appreciate an answer for `rest-client` since it has the nicer interface.